# How can I verify that the text corrosponding to configured text data is present in a table using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE to automate the testing of GUI of my company.At a point my manual test case say that 
"Verify that the view screen display the data corresponding to configured data.".
After I insert any node the node get inserted in the table which contain node name and its inside values in front of it. Now I have to verify that whether this node has been inserted or not using Selenium IDE
I tried verifytextpresent command but it is not working .
The problem I am facing is that there is no ID of the table and its inside rows and columns.
What commands should I use to solve this problem.

Comment: You might want to consider learning XPath. Start here: http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using javascript -

If there's a class name associated with it, use getElementsByClass

Else, you can always use getElementsbyTagName

Cheers